# How to Create a Custom ListView Qt?

Tags: qt, qt5

I looked for references online but could not find any solution which can specifically solve my problem. Now, Pardon me if this question has already been answered or is too basic. I am looking to build a control/widget like this in Qt. What widget is better suited for this, and where do I begin? I am thinking of QTableView and QListView.

[image]

Comment: You need to be more specific about the behaviour of this control. For example, exactly what happens when you choose another folder like "Submissions"? You may want QTreeView instead.

Comment: You should take a look at the `QStyledItemDelegate`